# How can i get Test Report with TestNG frame work with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to produce Test Reoprt in TestNG.Currently working on **Selenium WebDriver**, **Java** and **TestNG** frame work.

Please give ideas about **TestNG** framework.

- For example, i have a file **test.java**. I have written java code with
  **@BeforeTest** , **@Test**, **@AfterTest**. while running the code each test is running and am getting how many test got passed and how many got failed.
- But i want solution for the secnario:
- I have two tabs called **Default** and **Internal vs External**

[image]

- After clicking the default tab i want run many test for that particular tab, once those test executed then i need to click on the Internal vs External then i need to run all test belongs to that tab.
- How can i get result in the TestNG frame work.

The following code:

```
public class OverviewAndEvolutionPR{
private static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(OverviewAndEvolutionPR.class.getName());
private WebDriver driver;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
Properties p= new Properties();
public Selenium selenium;
//@BeforeMethod
@BeforeTest
public void Login() throws Exception {
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 try {
 p.load(new FileInputStream("C:/Login.txt"));
 } catch (Exception e) {
 e.getMessage();
 }
 String url=p.getProperty("url");
 DOMConfigurator.configure("src/log4j.xml");
 Log.info("______________________________________________________________");
 Log.info("Initializing Selenium...");
 selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox",url);
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 Log.info("Selenium instance started");
 try {
 p.load(new FileInputStream("C:/Login.txt"));
 } catch (Exception e) {
 e.getMessage();
 }
 Log.info("Accessing Stored uid,pwd from the stored text file");
 String uid=p.getProperty("loginUsername");
 String pwd=p.getProperty("loginPassword");
 Log.info("Retrieved uid pwd from the text file");
 try
 {
 driver.get("https://test.com");//example i had given like this
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
 Reporter.log("network server is slow..check internet connection");
 Log.info("Unable to open the website");
 throw new Error("network server is slow..check internet connection");
 }
 performLogin(uid,pwd);
 }  
 public void performLogin(String uid,String pwd) throws Exception  
 {
 Log.info("Sign in to the OneReports website");
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 Log.info("Enter Username");
 driver.findElement(By.id("loginUsername")).sendKeys(uid);
 Log.info("Enter Password");
 driver.findElement(By.id("loginPassword")).sendKeys(pwd); 
 //submit
 Log.info("Submitting login details");
 waitforElement(driver,120 , "//*[@id='submit']");
 driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).submit();
 Thread.sleep(6000);
 Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
 Log.info("Clicking on Reports link");
 if(existsElement("reports")==true){
 WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("reports"));
 actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
 Thread.sleep(6000);
 }
 else{
 Log.info("element not present");
System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");
}
Log.info("Clicking on Extranet link");
if(existsElement("extranet")==true){
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("extranet"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
Thread.sleep(6000);
}
else{
Log.info("element not present");
System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");
}
Log.info("Clicking on PR link");
if(existsElement("ext-pr")==true){
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("ext-pr"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
Thread.sleep(6000);
}
else{ 
Log.info("element not present");
System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");
}
Log.info("Clicking on Overview and Evolution PR link");
if(existsElement("ext-pr-backlog-evolution")==true){
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.id("ext-pr-backlog-evolution") ));
Thread.sleep(6000);
}
else{
Log.info("element not present");
System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");
}
}
//Filter selection-1
//This filter selection need to happen in Default tab
@Test()
public void Filterselection_1() throws Exception{
Log.info("Clicking on Visualization dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('visualizationId').style.display='block';");
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationId")));
select.selectByVisibleText("Week");
Thread.sleep(6000);
Log.info("Clicking on Period dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor1 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor1.executeScript("document.getElementById('periodId').style.display='block';");
Select select1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("periodId")));
select1.selectByVisibleText("Last 4 Weeks");
Thread.sleep(6000); 
Log.info("Clicking on Type dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor2 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor2.executeScript("document.getElementById('classificationId').style.display='block';");
Select select2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("classificationId")));
select2.selectByVisibleText("Customer PRs");
Thread.sleep(6000);
Log.info("Clicking on Apply Filter button");
driver.findElement(By.id("kpiFilterSubmit")).click();
}
//In the default tab many filter section i will have once it completed then i need to move to other tab and need to check the filter selection
//Filter selection-2
//It need to happen in the Internal vs External tab
@Test
public void Filterselection_2() throws Exception{
Log.info("Clicking Internal Vs External tab");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Internal vs External")).click();
Thread.sleep(6000);
Log.info("Clicking on Visualization dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor3 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor3.executeScript("document.getElementById('visualizationId').style.display='block';");
Select select3 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationId")));
select3.selectByVisibleText("ICC");
Thread.sleep(6000);
Log.info("Clicking on Type dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor02 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor02.executeScript("document.getElementById('classificationId').style.display='block';");
Select select02 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("classificationId")));
select02.selectByVisibleText("Internal PRs");
Thread.sleep(6000);
Log.info("Clicking on topography dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor4= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor4.executeScript("document.getElementById('topographyId').style.display='block';");
Select select4 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("topographyId")));
select4.selectByVisibleText("ICC");
Thread.sleep(6000); 
Log.info("Clicking on Apply Filter button");
driver.findElement(By.id("kpiFilterSubmit")).click();
Thread.sleep(6000);
}
private boolean existsElement(String id) {
try {
driver.findElement(By.id(id));
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("id is not present ");
return false;
}
return true;
}
private void waitforElement(WebDriver driver2, int i, String string) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
//@AfterMethod
@AfterTest
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
Log.info("Stopping Selenium...");
Log.info("______________________________________________________________"); 
driver.quit();
String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
Assert.fail(verificationErrorString);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Can any one help me to this scenario

Answer (score 2):

TestNG has by default mechanism for the report and it will automatically generate HTML report into test-output directory once you execute the test.

you can find a report from below path

```
your project directory/test-output/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

before second test write

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods="Filterselection_1")
```

That way you will execute second test only after Filterseclection_1 is ended, and tests will not be run at the same time. By default TestNG runs test in parallel(you could change it, but it is not recommended).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please provide a little more context to your answers, rather than just code.  Why before the second test, for example?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you can use TestNG group and depends on annotations.
Create two groups
 @Test (groups = {"Default Tab"}) = write this for all tests you want to run in default scenario.
 @Test (groups = {"Internal vs External Tab"}): write this for all tests you want to run in default scenario.
 Alos for @Test (groups = {" Internal vs External Tab"}) you have to use attributes “dependsOnGroups” in @Test annotations along with groups annotations.

OR
Alternatively, you can specify your group dependencies in the testng.xml file. You use the `<dependencies>` tag to achieve this:

```css
<test name="My suite">
  <groups>
    <dependencies>
      <group name="Internal vs External Tab" depends-on=" Default Tab" />
    </dependencies>
  </groups>
</test>
```

For more detail:
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups